# "does not match format" error parsing date time from string

Tags: python

Trying to parse time from string, but get this error. Tried few formatting string.

### Error:

```
time data '10/2/2010 0:00:00' does not match format '"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"'
```

### code:

```
strdt = '10/2/2010 0:00:00'
dt = datetime.strptime(strdt, '"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"')
```

Comment: You must use two numbers in hours.  http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html?highlight=strptime#strftime-strptime-behavior

Comment: To be fair @MetalRain, when someone is trying to parse a date-time string they normally don't have much choice in how it is formatted.

Comment: @MetalRain it appears to be more forgiving in practice, I tested it just fine. It might depend on your platform though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your format has quotes in it. Take those out.

```
dt = datetime.strptime(strdt, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: And to verify this: If you set `strdt = '"10/2/2010 0:00:00"'` the original version works and this one doesn't. As the documentation says, every non-format character is treated as a literal that must be matched exactly, so those quotes are required to match exactly.

Answer (score 2):

try to remove quotes from format '"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"' -> '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use [dateutil](http://niemeyer.net/python-dateutil):

```
In [68]: import dateutil.parser as parser

In [69]: parser.parse('10/2/2010 0:00:00')
Out[69]: datetime.datetime(2010, 10, 2, 0, 0)
```

---

Note that by default, `parser.parse` interprets `10/2/2010` as being in `MM/D/YYYY` format.

If your string has the day before the month, then use

```
parser.parse("10/2/2010", dayfirst = True)
```

There is also the yearfirst option; see [the docs](http://niemeyer.net/python-dateutil) for more details.

Comment: How does dateutil resolve `m/d` vs. `d/m`? `m/d` is pretty universal in the US while `d/m` seems to be the standard everywhere else.

Comment: @MarkRansom: From the [docs](http://niemeyer.net/python-dateutil#head-c0e81a473b647dfa787dc11e8c69557ec2c3ecd2) "Whenever an ambiguous date is found, the `dayfirst` and `yearfirst` parameters will control how the information is processed."  The default is `dayfirst=False`, meaning that "MM-DD-YYYY format will have precedence over DD-MM-YYYY in an ambiguous date."  I think it is important to call this detail out in the answer because it will surprise non-US developers.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Except in many Asian countries, where dates are usually m/d because the overall format is y/m/d…

Comment: `dateutil.parse` with `not dayfirst and not yearfirst` isn't quite the same as m/d/y, especially if you can't trust your data (which seems plausible given the string the OP is trying to parse). In particular, if you get something like '13/6/2010' in your input, you probably want an error, but instead you're going to get June 13th. On the other hand, you might _want_ June 13th, because you're using it as part of a very forgiving GUI interface, in which case dateutil is better. The OP should choose based on which one does what you want, not which one he can get working first.